# YouTube REST client with Delphi

Tags: json, rest, delphi, youtube

I am developing a rest client that fetched data from YouTube using their API. When a REST request is completed I am putting the data in a Memory Table component and then make it display in a grid.

The REST request etc. works fine, I am getting data back, however, the data that is set in items (field snippet) is JSON encoded and obvious shows as JSON encoded string in the grid (column snippet).

Is there a way so I can display the data as expected, hence get the data that is stored inside items -> snippets to display in the grid or memory table?

One way I could think of is to go trough the memory table, parse the data and insert it into another memory table to display the data correctly...but I think there must be an easier way to do it.

Below a screenshot from the REST Debugger, the data is displayed the same in the grid / memory table. What I would need is to get the data from the snippet column to display correctly in the grid / memory table.

To process the REST request I am using the standard Delphi components such as RESTClient, RESTRequest, RESTResponse, etc.

I've tried to change the root element to snippets and items/snippets but these give an error saying something in the line that it can not be added because it does not exist as a root element.

[image: Result from YouTube API Request]

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding your situation, without any code or screenshots.

Comment: @JerryDodge I've added a screenshot, I hope it is clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe parse the json before adding to the memory table, see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150592/delphi-json-parser

Comment: Do you use FireDAC? How do you process the response?

Comment: Create a calculated field. In the table's `OnCalcFields` event, parse the data and set the field's `AsString` value to the snippet you want to display. Connect the DBGrid.Column to that calculated field.

Comment: Try to use another address in root Element. For example `items/snippet` or `snippet`

Comment: I've updated my question with some of the suggestions given, so far no cigar. :(