# TJSONObject with anonymous JSON values give Exception EListError

Tags: json, delphi, parsing

I m parsing and go threw a JSON structure, in Delphi XE8, and it gives me an error because of the JSON Structure. if i use the REST Debugger i can see the data in the grid but if i try to get it manually i get an error.

here is the JSON :

```json
{
  "S":1,
  "U":"2898",
  "F":[],
  "D":[
    {
      "PRJCT_ID":"7",
      "PRJCT_NAME":"Hotel La Rosiere",
      "PRJCT_ADRESS":"le plateau"
    },  
    {
      "PRJCT_ID":"8",
      "PRJCT_NAME":"Hotel Delux",
      "PRJCT_ADRESS":"Centre Maison"
    },
    {
      "PRJCT_ID":"9",
      "PRJCT_NAME":"villedieu",
      "PRJCT_ADRESS":""
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get the Pair list from level 1 properly : S, F, D

But how can i test if the data is an anonymous record of data : 
i tried :

```
 if JSO.Pairs[i].JsonString.Value = '' then
```

I get an Exception EListError Message... which is normal because no JSON Key associated for the value  "{"PRJCT_ID":"7","PRJCT_NAME":"Hotel La Rosiere","PRJCT_ADRESS":"le plateau"}"

My code is

```
procedure TAArray2.ExtractValues(JSO : TJsonObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  try
    i := 0;
    while (i < JSO.Count) do
    begin
      if JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue is TJSONArray then   // array of values "Key":[{"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"},{"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"}]
      begin
        AddItem(JSO.Pairs[i].JsonString.Value, '', TJSonObject(JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue)); // recursive call ExtractValues(TJSonObject(JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue))
      end
      else if JSO.Pairs[i].JsonString.Value = '' then  // ERROR HERE : anonymous key : {"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"},{"Key":"Value","Key":"Value"} 
      begin
        AddItem(i, JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue.Value);
      end
      else // standard creation : "Key":"Value"
      begin
        AddItem(JSO.Pairs[i].JsonString.Value, JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue.Value);
      end;
      inc(i);
    end;
  finally

  end;
end;
```

How can i do it ? Does anyone get an idea ?

> Nota : i call anonymous JSON Record Set the portion of JSON that don't
>   is member of Array "D" like we could say : "D[1]":{ "PRJCT_ID":"7",
>   "PRJCT_NAME":"Hotel La Rosiere", "PRJCT_ADRESS":"le plateau"} i call it anonymouse because this record set doesn't have his own Reference Key.

Here is the full code : about building a dictionnary of TREE - data accessing as well as Key string value or index : (Note i will only "Parse" the node if needed (Get), if not it will stay stored like a string)

```
unit Unit3;

interface

 uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types, REST.Types, System.JSON, Data.Bind.Components,
  System.RegularExpressions, System.Variants,
  Generics.Collections;

type

  TAArray2 = class;

  PTRec=^TRec;

  TRec = class
  public
    Key : Variant;
    isRequired : boolean;
    Value : Variant;
    OldValue : Variant;
    JSON : string;
    JSO : TJSonObject;
    Items : TAArray2;
    procedure Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
  end;

   TAArray2 = class(TDictionary<Variant, TRec>)
   private
     function Get(Index: variant): TRec;
    procedure ExtractValues(JSO : TJsonObject);
   public
    procedure AddItem(Key: Variant; Value: Variant ; JSOnObject : TJSOnObject = nil);
    procedure ExtractFromJSON(JSonString: string ; RootElement : string = '');
     property Items[Cle : Variant]: TRec read Get; default;
   end;

implementation

procedure TRec.Add(Key : Variant ; Value: TRec);
begin
  if not(assigned(items)) then
    self.Items := TAArray2.Create;
  Items.Add( Key, Value);

end;

procedure TAArray2.AddItem(Key : Variant ; Value: Variant ; JSOnObject : TJSOnObject = nil);
var
  LocalRec : TRec;
begin

  LocalRec := Get(Key);

  if assigned(LocalRec) then
  begin

    LocalRec.Key := Key;
    LocalRec.Value := Value;
    LocalRec.JSO := JSOnObject;
  end
  else
  begin

   LocalRec := TRec.Create;
    LocalRec.Value := Value;
    LocalRec.Key := Key;
    LocalRec.JSO := JSOnObject;
    inherited Add( Key, LocalRec);

  end;

end;


function TAArray2.Get(Index: Variant): TRec;
var
  LocalRec : TRec;
begin

  if self.ContainsKey(Index) then
  begin
    LocalRec := inherited items[Index];
    if (LocalRec.JSON <> '') or (LocalRec.JSO <> nil) then
    begin
      LocalRec.Items := TAArray2.Create;

//      ExtractValues(JSO);
    end;

    Result := LocalRec;
  end
  else
  begin
    result := nil;

  end;

end;



// *****************************************************************************
//
// *****************************************************************************

procedure TAArray2.ExtractFromJSON(JSonString: string ; RootElement : string = '');
var
  JSO : TJsonObject;
  JSP : TJSonPair;
begin

  try
    JSO := TJSOnObject.ParseJSONValue(JSonString) as TJSONObject;

    try
      if (RootElement <> '') then
      begin
        JSP := JSO.Get(RootElement);
        if not(JSP.Null) then
        begin
          ExtractValues(TJSonObject(JSP.JsonValue));
        end;
      end
      else if Not(JSO.Null) then
      begin
        ExtractValues(JSO);
      end;

    finally
       JSO.Free();
    end;

  except
    on E:Exception do showmessage('Data Structure Error');
  end;
end;
```

I view the content with this code :

```
procedure TForm1.ShowAssocArray2(AAA : TAArray2 ; Level : integer);
var
  i : Integer;
  s : string;
  MyRec : TRec;
begin
  s := DupeString(' ',Level * 4);
  for MyRec in AAA.Values Do
  begin
    memo2.Lines.Add(s + string(MyRec.Key) + ' = ' + string(MyRec.Value) + ' (' + string(MyRec.JSON) + ')');  // Error Here
    AAA[MyRec.Key];
    if assigned(MyRec.Items) then
    begin
      if MyRec.Items.Count > 0 then
        ShowAssocArray2(MyRec.items, Level + 1);   // recursive for childrens
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyList: TAArray2;
  MyRec, MyRec2 : TRec;
  i: Integer;
begin
  MyList := TAArray2.Create;
  MyList.ExtractFromJSON(Memo1.Lines.Text);

  ShowAssocArray2(MyList, 0);

end;
```

Comment: JSON is not valid, comma is missing after "2898". Have you tried to search? You should probably not use JsonString if you don't know the format. Eg. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808912/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-in-delphi-xe2

Comment: Now the JSON is valid (i cut it manualy for easier understanding).  I read the article, and i use the same technic. But the difference is my JSON get anonymous value (without reference key : JSonString). And the Pair is assigned (without JSonString reference)

Comment: There is no such thing as an "anonymous" value in JSON.  Everything has a name, and everything in your JSON has a name.

Comment: Did you check my JSON ? the Key D have an array of 3 records that contain each 3 fields... Each record is anonymous because there is not a name like "record1":"{ "PRJCT_ID":"7", "PRJCT_NAME":"Hotel La Rosiere", "PRJCT_ADRESS":"le plateau"} . There is no name for this but i need to extract this record as it is and put a number. The JSON is correct because the REST debugger in delphi can read it properly. And i use this way of data since more than 5 years, it never cause problem in PHP, or Ajax, Or even if i use DataSetRestAdapter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the array correctly.  When you find a `TJSONArray`, you are type-casting it to `TJSONObject`, but an array is not an object.  You would have gotten a runtime error had you used the `as` operator for the type-cast, but you did not.

You need to do something more like this instead:

```
procedure TAArray2.ExtractValues(JSO : TJSONObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  pair: TJSONPair;
  arr: TJSONArray;
  value: TJSONvalue;
begin
  for i := 0 to JSO.Count-1 do
  begin
    pair := JSO.Pairs[i];
    value := pair.JsonValue;
    if value is TJSONArray then
    begin
      arr := TJSONArray(value);
      for j := 0 to arr.Count-1 do
      begin
        value := arr[j];
        if value is TJSONObject then
        begin
          ExtractValues(TJSONObject(value));
        end
        else
        begin
          // value is not an object, do something else...
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      AddItem(pair.JsonString.Value, value.Value);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Update**: the JSON document is already in a tree structure.  If you are trying to display that tree to the user, such as in a `TTreeView`, then you can use something like this:

```
function TAArray2.AddJSONValueToTreeView(const Name: String; Value: TJSONValue; ParentNode: TTreeNode = nil): TTreeNode;
var
  i: integer;
  obj: TJSONObject;
  pair: TJSONPair;
  arr: TJSONArray;
begin
  if ParentNode <> nil then
    Result := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, Name);
  else
    Result := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, Name);
  if Value is TJSONObject then
  begin
    obj := TJSONObject(Value);
    for i := 0 to obj.Count-1 do
    begin
      pair := obj.Pairs[i];
      AddJSONValueToTreeView(pair.JsonString.Value, pair.JsonValue, Result);
    end;
  end
  else if Value is TJSONArray then
  begin
    arr := TJSONArray(Value);
    for i := 0 to arr.Count-1 do
    begin
      AddJSONValueToTreeView('['+IntToStr(i)+']', arr.Items[i], Result);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Result, Value.Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: U extracting all the data from the same level. This can't work because at the end : PRJCT_ID = 9 which is not right because there is 3 records with PRJCT_ID = 7 then 8 then 9... that's why i ask. I need to make a difference from the anonymous JSON RecordSet. (i did that before already. and it's not my need).

Comment: about what u said "You are not accessing the array correctly. When you find a TJSONArray, you are type-casting it to TJSONObject, but an array is not an object."... IT WORK PROPERLY i don't have any runtime error and i can get all the values the same way you do it, if i don't care about the anonymous Record. NO TYPECAST Error.

Comment: The problem is i need to really create the same kind of Tree structure that the data give :
D :
 1 : 
  PRJCT_ID:"7"
  PRJCT_NAME:"Hotel La Rosiere"
  PRJCT_ADRESS:"le plateau" 
 2 : { fields }
  PRJCT_ID:"8"
  PRJCT_NAME:"Hotel Delux"
  PRJCT_ADRESS:"Centre Maison"
 3 : { fields }
  PRJCT_ID:"9"
  PRJCT_NAME:"villedieu"
  PRJCT_ADRESS:"" 

Where 1, 2, 3 is a level / branch than contain every record set

Comment: @FabienFert: Your original code said "*recursive call ExtractValues(TJSonObject(JSO.Pairs[i].JsonValue))*", so I made `ExtractValues()` actually recurse itself, as you did not show what your `AddItem()` methods are actually doing. But you can clearly see that my code is recursing through arrays.

Comment: @FabienFert: You *CANNOT* type-cast a `TJSONArray` to a `TJSONObject`. They do not derive from each other, they both derive from `TJSONValue` instead. You did not get a runtime error on the type-cast because you were not performing a type-cast that performs a runtime validation to begin with. But you did get a runtime error when trying to access `TJSONObject` fields on a `TJSONArray` object.

Comment: i understand what u said about Recursive call : so i try to replace with this  : AddItem(Value.JsonString.Value, '', TJSONObject(value));  i can't compile, because i can't get JSonString.Value from Value... if i do AddItem(Pair.JsonString.Value, '', TJSONObject(value));... then it will go threw the whole JSON, but the result will be an empty one : D : "" !!! the problem still the same... need to be able to identify each recordset (if i use Pair.JSonString then it will stay in D )

Comment: @FabienFert: You still have not shown your actual `AddItem()` code.  What EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish?  What EXACTLY are you trying to do with the extracted JSON values?  Please update your question with those details.

Comment: thank you. I updated the code. Maybe it's more clear ?

Comment: it helps... thank you. Finaly i did other way but your code is useful.